# Cleaner way to write the following

Tags: perl

What would be the most efficient way to write the following code in Perl:

```
my $index = 0;
foreach ( @spec ) {
    if ( $module =~ m/$_/ ) {
        splice(@spec, $index, 0, $module);
        last;         
    }
    $index++;
}
```

This works fine. Just seems a little wordy. The idea is that where I find a match for `$module` in the array I add an entry. I want to keep the array in a certain order and sorted.

i.e. if my array was `[a,b,c,d]` and my `$module` was '`c`', I would want the result array to be `[a,b,c,c,d]`.

Comment: This sounds like it would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Any optimizations are going to be micro at best.. there is nothing wrong with your program.

Comment: Are you simply doing an *insert sort??*

Comment: Now found on codereview [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26026/cleaner-way-to-write-the-following)

Comment: @0A0D - there's a difference between performance optimization (which is the root of all evil) and the readability optimization (which is Good)

Comment: @DVK: It's optimized for readability already, which is what I was getting at.

Comment: Wouldn't `@spec = sort (@spec, $module)` be more readable?

Answer (score 5):

You want "more efficient wordiness"??? I presume you're not asking for golfing, but for more readable code.

```
@spec = map { $_ eq $module ? ($_, $_) : $_ } @spec;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops offers this wisdom:

> If any part of LIST is an array, foreach will get very confused if you add or remove elements within the loop body, for example with splice. So don't do that.

If you must do that (and it isn't appropriate in this case), do it like this:

```
for ( my $index = 0; $index < @array; ++$index ) {
    my $elem = $array[$index];
    if ( ... ) {
        splice( @array, $index, 0, $elem );
        ++$index;
    }
}
```

or this:

```
for ( my $index = $#array; $index >= 0; --$index ) {
    my $elem = $array[$index];
    if ( ... ) {
        splice( @array, $index, 0, $elem );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty much what I'd do except I'd be hesitant to manipulate an array while you're parsing through it with a `for` loop.

I would go through my array, find the position, then *outside of the loop* do the splice:

```
my $module_index;
for my $spec_index ( 0..$#spec ) {
    my $item = $spec[$spec_index];
    if ( $module =~ /$item/ ) {
        $module_index = $spec_index;
        last;
    }
}
splice (@spec, $module_index, 0, $module);
```

Note that I use the `0..$#spec` to index through my array. This way, I don't have to increment my $module_index. There isn't anyway, using *this* syntax, to allow for `$spec_index` to have a value set from the loop itself. The choices are using `while` loop or using the C style syntax:

```
my $spec_index;
for ( $spec_index = 0; $spec_index <= $#spec; $spec_index++) {
    my $item = $spec[$spec_index];
    last if $module =~ /$item/;
}
splice (@spec, $spec_index, 0, $module);
```

However, the use of `C style for loops` is considered *déclassé*, or at least hard to maintain. According to Damian Conway (Perl Best Practices):

> The three-part for statements that Perl inherits from C are needed only for unusual loop control behaviour, such as iterating by twos, or in an irregular sequence. But even in such cases, these C-style loops provide that unusual behaviour in an obscure and harder-to-maintain way.

There are ways to do this with `map` and `grep` which would take less typing, but I'm not sure whether they would be *better*. You already have an optimal answer with [map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16483060/368630), but can you look at it and tell without going through it what it's doing?

The question is one of support. What would happen if someone else looking at your code was trying to figure out what is going on?